# Is your coffee bottomless?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language, register

Which of the following is more natural for a customer to use at a coffee shop?

> a. Do you offer free refills on coffee?
>
> b. Is your coffee bottomless?

Comment: I think it would be the coffee **pot** which is bottomless.

Answer (score 2):

**bottomless** in this context is late 20th century ad-speak.  It isn't really a "natural" idiom that has been used for centuries.

P.S. Although I agree with Weather Vane that it is the pot (or the mug) that is bottomless, you might well see a poster or a billboard advertising BOTTOMLESS COFFEE at a donut shop or fast-food restaurant.

P.P.S. A speaker might ask the question in either way. It is not uncommon for speakers to use the ad-speak that saturates commercial culture.  "Free refills" would be understood anywhere. If you were to ask "Is your coffee bottomless?" in an area which is not saturated with ad-speak (they are few and far between) you might get a strange look.

Comment: Does that mean option (a) is natural?

Comment: "Free refills" is also a phrase that became popular in the second half of the 20th century. But the word **refill** (with medical prescriptions and beverages) is in common use now, so that sentence is natural enough, at least in AmE.

Comment: In a coffee shop or fast food restaurant, a customer would ask "Do you offer free refills on coffee," not "Is your coffee bottomless," right?

Comment: I've added a second postscript.

Comment: On a poster is it common to see "bottomless" to go with other drinks like "soda"?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the use of the word **bottomless** with soft-drinks, or about the practice in general? The practice is common enough but I don't think the word "bottomless" is used often with soft drinks, perhaps because the ad-men don't want to remind consumers that they cause obesity.  :)

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/is-your-coffee-bottomless.3505893/#post-17806839 It  seems that many people there are not familiar with "bottomless coffee" used by a customer at a coffee shop.

Comment: What do you want me to do with that bit of info, that some people on that forum have never seen such usage?  https://www.google.com/search?q=bottomless+coffee&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU68Ki1fTdAhUGTN8KHXzABbwQ_AUIDigB&biw=1757&bih=1006

Comment: Maybe that usage is not so common and limited to the menu?

Comment: No, it is not limited to the menu and it is almost ubiquitous.  Did you even bother to look at the images on the link I gave?